# I have 18 brand new laptops - how can i blanket install software (quickest)

Tags: windows, administrator

So my work received a delivery of 18 laptops, all windows 8 and full of bloatware. Is there any way I can format, install W7 and all the software needed easily and efficiently for all 18?

Am i going to be here all weekend?

Comment: There are many ways, it is hard to tell which would be ideal for you. I guess if you only have 18 machines to cover, a USB memory stick based solution would be fine. The general idea would be to prepare one machine, "scan" it (or use a regular backup software) and once that has been rolled out to the other 17 machines individualize them (for Product Key etc.). But there are many other ways with their pros and cons. You might also want to mention which edition of Win7 you are trying to install. The real time killer might be updating, look into WSUS Offline Update.

Comment: Its dead simply to create an image that can be used on each machine but it requires you to have 18 Windows 7 licenses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the options is to set up everything on one machine. Keep in mind that if the application licensing model requires individual licensing on each machine, leave it for later. 
Then, use an imaging tool to create a disk image, and restore in on other machines, one by one. When done, license the software

I use [Acronis](http://www.acronis.com/en-us/articles/imaging-software/#1) and have been quite satisfied with it - it's quick and reliable

Comment: Imaging is the way to go.  Clonezilla and Ghost are also good imaging tools.  Be sure to use Sysprep though.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721940(v=ws.10).aspx